# consume hhtp post request in Angular 9

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular and try to consume web API in angular 9. My http get request working well but when I  send hhtp post request I find the following errors
    zone-evergreen.js:2845 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/insert 500 (Internal Server Error)
    core.js:6189 ERROR 
    In post request i have made a create-user component and a service. The web API which I have created is in LARAVEL.I used POSTMAN tool to submit GET/PUT/POST/DELETE and these requests are working well but in angular get request is working and post request is not working.
    I could not find the reason of the following errors.Please I request to help me to solve this problem. I shall be very thankful.
    code of my different files is given below

```
**user.service.ts**

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getUser(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/basic');
  }
  addUser(form: any): Observable<any> {

    return this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/insert', form);
  }
}

create-user.component.html
<br><br>
<form #form="ngForm" (submit)="onSubmit(form)">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ngModel placeholder="Enter Name">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" mgModel aria-describedby="emailHelp"
      placeholder="Enter email">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" ngModel placeholder="Password">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
create-user.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { UserService } from '../services/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-user',
  templateUrl: './create-user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-user.component.css']
})
export class CreateUserComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    this.service.addUser(form.value).subscribe(
      res => {
        alert('data has been added');
      }
    )
    console.log(form.value);
  }

}
```

Comment: You are getting `Internal Server Error` in your angular app which means there is usually some error on the server side. You need to check the larval application for logs/debug of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the response is a 500 Internal server error. The issue is with your Laravel backend.

What I would suggest is put on some debug logging in your Laravel setup and see what error is occuring there.  Also to be 100% sure, just open your developer dev tools in Google Chrome (F12) and select the "Network" tab to inspect the request you are submitting to your backend.

Verify if the POST body is correct, because it might be that the 500 Internal server error is triggered because you are sending the wrong data, or incorrectly formated data to your backend.